# `Use managed compatibility mode` or `Enable native code debugging`?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I write .net-plugins for Autodesk Revit. Revit is unmanaged application. So, for successfully debugging I am to set into `ON` either for `Use managed compatibility mode` option or for `Enable native code debugging` option (or for both of them). Otherwise debugging cannot be launched.

The first of them is applied for all projects. The second of them is used for each project individually.

[image]

What the difference of these options? I don't understand what they do. What option it is more correct to use in my case?

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Your screenshot saved me at least 3 additional business days which I would have had to spend in debugging some dynamically loaded assemblies in a cranky way which was worse than `window.alert` debugging methodology of JavaScript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not have to enable unmanaged debugging to debug your plugin.  Breakpoints in your code will activate (turn from hollow to solid) when the host application loads your add-in.  If you are not sure if this happened then have a look at the Debug > Windows > Modules window.

Enabling unmanaged debugging does not otherwise greatly affect the debugging session, it can however take quite a bit longer to get started and you may need to temporarily disable the symbol server to avoid getting annoyed at it.

The Tools > Options settings have rather poor names.  Microsoft has been working on new debugging engines but was forced (or chose) to drop some features.  "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" forces an older version of the managed debugger to be loaded, the one that was used in VS2010.  It is required when you debug C++/CLI code.  It can be also useful in VS2015, its managed debugging engine is very buggy. You'll miss out on some new debugging features like return value inspection and 64-bit edit+continue.  You don't otherwise need it to debug your add-in.

Much the same story for "Use Native Compatibility Mode", it enables an older version of the unmanaged debugging engine, the one in VS2012 afaik.  You'll miss out on the new Natvis visualizers.  I have not yet found a compelling reason to need it, other than keep the old visualizers working.

Comment: Your advice works fine on my office computer: I use the `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` option only and the debugging works fine. But on my home computer the debugging works only when both options are turned on. Here is video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8n-KjyQ-uw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` is no longer available on VS 2022, what can I do?