# What exactly does Use Managed Compatability Mode disabled

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

So I've been struggling with visual studio debugger timeout out on large entity framework queries for a while now. Basically sometimes when stepping over a entity framework linq query it would give me this error.

> Evaluating the function
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery.ToString' timed
>   out and needed to be aborted in an unsafe way. This may have corrupted
>   the target process.
>
> If the problem happens regularly, consider disabling the
>   Tools->Options setting "Debugging->General->Enable property evaluation
>   and other implicit function calls" or change the code to disable
>   evaluation of this method. See help for information on doing this.

Once i had the error i would need to restart the debugger to fix it. After a tone of research and hair pulling i came across a suggestion to enable "Use Managed Compatibility Mode". Amazingly this worked and i also noticed a significant increase in the speed that i could step through my code.

The documentation says that this is a legacy debugger and enabling it may disable some debug features.

So what exactly is the feature difference and why does using "Managed Compatibility Mode" improve step speed so much?

Comment: I've been posting this recommendation ever since the new managed debugging engine became unstable in VS2013.  Unfortunately Microsoft does not want to properly document it, so solid advice is hard to come by.  What the option does is re-enable the debugging engine that was used in VS2010.  The good one.  What you'll miss out on are the new debugging features added since 2012.  Definitely method return value inspection and 64-bit edit+continue.  Iffy for UWP and .NETCore projects.  The only warranty I can give is that  everybody is always ecstatic over the advice, debugger bugs suck heavy.

Comment: Thanks, that adds some more insight. It's interesting that the new inline property evaluation still works. It must not be directly tied to the debugger. I haven't noticed anything that i use often that is missing. It sounds like it might be more of an issue when we move to .net core though.

Comment: @Ryan B, I agree with Hans Passant's suggestion, that option forces an older version of the managed debugger to be loaded. Based on Hans Passant's suggestion, add the comment as an answer. Hope it could help other community members who get the same issue easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I know that it is a new option from VS2013

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/

In old VS version, C# and VB projects do not have a way to turn off managed debugging.

The option "Managed Compatibility Mode" was used to managed and mixed debugging but not to native-only debugging.

You could get much more detailed information from Hans Passant's suggestion here:

[`Use managed compatibility mode` or `Enable native code debugging`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158547/use-managed-compatibility-mode-or-enable-native-code-debugging)

Comment: `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` is no longer available on VS 2022, what can I do?