# unable to edit the c# code while debugging in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#

I am unable to edit the c# code in visual studio 2019 while debugging even I enabled the 'Edit and Continue' option at Tools -> Options -> Debugging. Getting prompt like this.

[image: Prompt message Image]

Comment: there are some unsupported code changes in Edit and Continue for c#.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/supported-code-changes-csharp?view=vs-2017

Comment: Hi Manoj, thanks for your reply. I have tried to add a new method in VS 2019 while debugging but its not allowing me to Key-in.

Answer (score 0):

I found one answer that maybe can help you. It says that with Managed Compatibility Mode you cannot edit and continue 64-bit application. Is it your issue?

[`Use managed compatibility mode` or `Enable native code debugging`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158547/use-managed-compatibility-mode-or-enable-native-code-debugging)